# Spring Cloud Kubernetes Service registry - Feign client - java.net.NoRouteToHostException

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-webclient, spring-cloud-kubernetes

There are two microservices (microservice-A & microservice-B), written in Spring boot, are talking to each other through the Feign Client and the services are registered in K8S Native service registry

Whenever a fresh deployment of a microservice-A is happening, the microservice-B that is already running in kubertnetes fails to make HTTP call to the freshly deployed service-A and below is the exception

```
feign.RetryableException: No route to host (Host unreachable) executing GET http://microserice-a/api/v1/myresources
```

This issue is getting resolved **immediately after restarting the microservice-B.**

When we googled for solutions, we got to see this link https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/769 and an user had given the below comment there

> I suspect the root cause is that FeignClient keeps an old list of service providers and the Ribbon cannot move correctly to the next node if one node has been destroyed

Not sure if that is correct root cause. Please comment If anyone has faced similar issue and solved it?